# Service is undefined?

Tags: ember.js

I have just started working with ember2.5.1. I wanted to try and create an easy service, and have a component implement it. The problem is that the service is always undefined, and I can't seem to call its methods.

/components/status-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  logger: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    test() {
      this.get('logger').log("testing");                                               
    } 
  } 
});
```

/services/logger.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  log(message) {                                                                
    console.log(message);
  }
});
```

Other information: I also attempted making routable components, and I'm not sure if that's messing up the services? I essentially have a route pointing to a dummy status-proxy-component.hbs which has the {{status-component}} within it. status-component.hbs is another file.

Any idea why this might not be working? Am I just plain out missing something from services, or is the proxy messing it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the get() function to get component properties.

`this.get('logger').log("testing");`

Comment: Whoops, I still had my test code in. That's what I was originally using, and it didn't work. Then I attempted using this.logger.log, which didn't work either. I will update my question.

Comment: Strange, it should work then. There is nothing wrong with it. Check out this twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/58588a0ce533b11d8a712d1a292fd845?openFiles=services.logger.js%2Ctemplates.components.log-button.hbs

Comment: I ended up creating another project from scratch, and was able to get this working. Thanks for the help, not sure what was wrong in the previous project.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. And, I don't have the patience to rewrite from scratch even though it is small. I wish i found what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ember 2.4.2; the service was defined in the correct location and would appear in the `ember build` output, but not in my running `ember serve`.

The problem turned out to be the hot reloading not picking up on the new service.  Killing the server and re-running `ember serve` allowed the service to work normally.